# How to paramaterize DAGs in airflow from UI?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Context: I've defined a airflow DAG which performs an operation, `compute_metrics`, on some data for an entity based on a parameter called `org`. Underneath something like `myapi.compute_metrics(org)` is called. This flow will mostly be run on an ad-hoc basis.

Problem: I'd like to be able to select the `org` to run the flow against when I manually trigger the DAG from the airflow UI.

The most straightforward solution I can think of is to generate `n` different DAGs, one for each org. The DAGs would have `id`s like: `compute_metrics_1`, `compute_metrics_2`, etc... and then when I need to trigger compute metrics for a single `org`, I can pick the DAG for that org. This doesn't scale as I add orgs and as I add more types of computation.

I've done some research and it seems that I can create a flask blueprint for airflow, which to my understanding, extends the UI. In this extended UI I can add input components, like a text box, for picking an org and then pass that as a `conf` to a `DagRun` which is manually created by the blueprint. Is that correct? I'm imaging I could write something like:

```
session = settings.Session()

execution_date = datetime.now()
run_id = 'external_trigger_' + execution_date.isoformat()

trigger = DagRun(
    dag_id='general_compute_metrics_needs_org_id',
    run_id=run_id,
    state=State.RUNNING,
    execution_date=execution_date,
    external_trigger=True,
    conf=org_ui_component.text) # pass the org id from a component in the blueprint
session.add(trigger)
session.commit() # I don't know if this would actually be scheduled by the scheduler
```

Is my idea sound? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Maybe a view is actually the right tool to use

Comment: can you post the code for the custom view you created to achieve this for others to use as an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've done some research and it seems that I can create a flask blueprint for airflow, which to my understanding, extends the UI.

The blueprint extends the API. If you want some UI for it, you'll need to serve a template view. The most feature-complete way of achieve this is developing your own [Airflow Plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html).

If you want to manually create `DagRun`s, you can use [this trigger](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/d99053106e58ec377333c64f68ee84ed1dcdf61c/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py) as reference. For simplicity, I'd trigger a Dag with the [API](https://airflow.apache.org/api.html#endpoints).

And specifically about your problem, I would have a single DAG `compute_metrics` that reads the `org` from an Airflow [Variable](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables). They are global and can be set dynamically. You can prefix the variable name with something like the DagRun id to make it unique and thus dag-concurrent safe.

Comment: I ended up using a custom view which uses a `TriggerDagOperator` to trigger a known DAG with a payload.